# Scala HMAC-SHA1 signing?

Tags: scala, sha1, hmac

I was wondering if there would be a way to get a HMAC-SHA1 signature in scala without having to compile a java class with the code everyone use in [java](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/index.html?AuthJavaSampleHMACSignature.html). Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what are you trying to do, but here http://technically.us/code/x/oauth-here-she-comes you can find an example of how to do HMAC-SHA1 (for OAuth) in Scala

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to avoid dealing with having Java source files in your Scala project, just translate the Java code into Scala.  It should be a very straightforward task.